# Using material animation on an entirely custom drawed View

Tags: android, material-design, ondraw

I've created a custom View which is entirely drawed in the "onDraw" method. This view is a sort of monthly calendar.
I draw rectangles that especially contains days number (1 to 31). I want to implement a long press on these rectangles to popup a dialog or a menu.
Is it possible to animate this rectangle like material design when the user long press on it ?
Is there helper methods from Google to "easy" implement that ?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: any reason not to use `myView.animate()...` ?